# shape.count property of constructor function shape

Tags: javascript, properties

Can anyone please explain what is `shape.count = ++shape.count || 1;` in this code.

```
function shape(shapeName){
    this.ShapeName = shapeName;
    shape.Count = ++shape.Count || 1;

    shape.ShowCount = function () {
      return shape.Count;
    }
  }
```

Comment: It will reset value of `shape.Count`to `1` if the current value is `-1`, other than that I don't see any significance.

Comment: Just a note:  all name casing here seems to be the opposite of what people class as standard.  eg. you have `shape` instead of `Shape`, you have `Count` and `ShowCount` instead of `count` `showCount`.  It will of course still work, but anybody else looking at your code may get well confused on what your variables and functions are doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
shape.count = ++shape.count || 1;
```

This will evaluate if shape.count is not defined or less than 1 it will assign shape.count to 1, if shape.count is defined then it will increment it and assign to itself.

More details on operators is below

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty weird code. You're using pre-incrementation here so the value of `++shape.Count` is `shape.Count + 1` ( and it update the value of `shape.Count` to `shape.Count + 1`).

This is useless as you're assigning to shape.Count in that statement, so it could be the same as

```
shape.Count = (shape.Count + 1) || 1;
```

The `||` is the or operator who is such that `a || b` equals `b` if `b` is a falsy value. In your case, as shape.Count is unitialized, `shapeCount + 1` will be `NaN` a falsy value, so it will properly initialize to 1 the first time.